# Using Microsoft Bot Framework, is it possible to @mention a team or channel in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I've got a bot built with the Microsoft Bot Framework (using C#), and I'm trying to mention a team or channel inside a channel conversation, which you can do while using Microsoft Teams as a user.  I'm able to mention a single user just fine, like below:

```
// I have previously created an Activity object called activity
var account = new ChannelAccount(accountId);
activity.AddMentionToText(account, MentionTextLocation.PrependText, "Firstname Lastname");
var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
var response = await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(activity);
```

Shows up like "**Firstname Lastname** messageText"

However, when I try to do it the same way, but using a team or channel Id instead, the mention does not work.  The message goes through, but it just looks like plain text, like:

"Channel Name messageText"

```
var account = new ChannelAccount(channelId);
activity.AddMentionToText(account, MentionTextLocation.PrependText, "Channel Name");
var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
var response = await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(activity);
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible?
Thanks!

Comment: I checked the source code of `Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Teams`, and it seems that it just enables us to specify mentioned user. You can try to [open an issue on github](https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams/issues) to report it.

Comment: I will, thanks for the help!

Comment: just to update my progress, I have submitted an issue here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams/issues/139

Comment: We actually have this working but haven't turned it on because doing so opens up potential for abuse which we haven't yet implemented the ability to detect or prevent. I'm investigating ways to turn this on without necessarily having to do that, but we don't have an ETA.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the response.  Just curious, what's the difference in risk of abuse between allowing a bot to mention specific users and allowing it to mention teams?  As it stands, a bot could already spam notifications if the dev wanted it to by mentioning many users at once.

Comment: True. It's not so much that, it's two things in particular. One, it doesn't respect the business logic for team and channel notifications (that can be turned off on a per-team basis) and for the General channel (for which channel notifications can be disabled for non-owners). Secondly, it's a service stability issue - a malicious bot could generate hundreds of thousands of fan-out notifications in a small number of calls.

Comment: I see. Well thanks for taking the time to communicate all of that with us here. I'm interested to hear what you decide to do, both as a stakeholder and as someone trying to learn.

Comment: @BillBliss-MSFT can you use directline channel from microsoft teams? is it safe to say that teams only work directly with /api/messages/ endpoint? -thanks

Comment: Hello, is this now available please? I'd like to @mention the general channel using the REST API